# Deleted projects in Azure DevOps remain in Visual Studio with their ID

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

After deleting 3 projects in Azure DevOps (VSTS) they are deleted there.
But in VS 2017 Team Explorer (Source Control Explorer) they are still there - without their name, but with an ID, e.g. `D486bb7b9-b159-441b-a9cd-8758c60c38e3`.

I cannot delete them there.

[image]

How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

You face this problem, because the project can be [recovered within 28 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/delete-project?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

> Projects are permanently deleted, if not restored within 28 days.

Azure DevOps implemented this feature to protect companies from mad employees and people who would harm the repositories.The only solution is to wait 28 days, before they are gone.

---

When the repository is not visible in Azure DevOps, you can remove the TFS repositories by using the [Destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts)

```
tf destroy [/keephistory] <itemspec1>[;<versionspec>][<itemspec2>...<itemspecN>] 
[/stopat:<versionspec>] [/preview] [/startcleanup] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/login:username,[password]] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]]
```

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately this is not my problem, because I deleted these projects more than 28 days ago. And only another one, which I deleted yesterday, appears in Azure DevOps under "Recently deleted projects". The three listed projects are not there.

Comment: VS403405: The item $/Ddefbb312-18c9-4c60-b773-5aa3366c5173 does not exist on the server, or you do not have permission to access it. :(

Comment: Is this a repository who only exists locally? Have you tried to remove the complete workspace and download it again? Sometimes branches remain locally while they are removed on the server.